# Saving value to a json file in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to save a json value to a `.json` file in Ionic 3. I have this code but I can't get it to work. I get this error of A URI supplied to the API was malformed. I am not connecting to an API. Please see my codes below:

```
fileName: string = "tickets.json";

saveTickets(obj: any) {
    return this.file.writeFile('src/assets/data/', this.fileName, JSON.stringify(obj), {replace: false});
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

```
writeFile(path, fileName, text, options)
```

`path` is not a path it's the name of one of the Base FileSystems listed below.

> path |    string  | **Base FileSystem**.

Base FileSystems:

> **applicationDirectory** Read-only directory where the application is
>   installed.
>
> **applicationStorageDirectory** Read-only directory where the application
>   is installed.
>
> **dataDirectory** Where to put app-specific data files.
>
> **cacheDirectory** Cached files that should survive app restarts. Apps
>   should not rely on the OS to delete files in here.
>
> **externalApplicationStorageDirectory** Android: the application space on
>   external storage.
>
> **externalDataDirectory** Android: Where to put app-specific data files on
>   external storage.
>
> **externalCacheDirectory** Android: the application cache on external
>   storage.
>
> **externalRootDirectory** Android: the external storage (SD card) root.
>
> **tempDirectory** iOS: Temp directory that the OS can clear at will.
>
> **syncedDataDirectory** iOS: Holds app-specific files that should be
>   synced (e.g. to iCloud).
>
> **documentsDirectory** iOS: Files private to the app, but that are
>   meaningful to other applications (e.g. Office files)
>
> **sharedDirectory** BlackBerry10: Files globally available to all apps

Comment: What should I choose so I can place it in my src/app/assets/data?

Comment: it's up to you (and your usecase) what you  choose `dataDirectory` is for data. `syncedDataDirectory` is for Data that is automatically backuped up to iCloud etc...

Comment: I have used this `this.result = this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'assets/data/tickets.json', JSON.stringify(preparedData), {replace: false});` but for some reason I can't get it to work. I don't get any errors. I just ge a t {__zone_symbo__state: null ....} in the console. I even used the this.result = this.file.writeFile(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'assets/data/tickets.json', JSON.stringify(preparedData), {replace: false});

Comment: can you read the file with readFile? Is it working without the path 'assets/data'? possibly you have to create the directories first...

Comment: I used this `this.result = this.file.readAsText(this.file.dataDirectory, 'assets/data/loginInfo.json');` and it gave me this error: `It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources`.

Comment: I am using the `>chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files` already.